# Podcast aggregator for Ipod other than itunes

Tags: windows-xp, podcasts

What is a good podcast aggregator for my ipod other than ITunes?

I'm looking for something that will poll for new podcasts daily and automatically load to my ipod when I connect my ipod to my computer.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Any specifics on why you don't want to use iTunes? If you want it to sync to your iPod, iTunes is probably genuinely the best program out there.

Comment: The only thing I have on my ipod are podcasts; no music. I want the simplest app for pulling podcasts down regularly and syncing them with my ipod.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a Mac or Linux? I don't know any Mac programs, but if you're running Linux - http://gPodder.org is a great tool for podcast aggregation.

Comment: rhythmbox doesnt talk to iPod?

Answer (score 1):

I think SongBird can sync to an iPod/iPhone. But for the best results to sync to an iPod, iTunes is simply the best.

Why? I have my podcasts to automatically delete off the iPod on a sync after they have been played. This on top of playlists and x2 speed for said podcasts.